# Why MYSQL doesn't use my indexes?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, indexing

I have table `karton00` which holds thousands of records. This makes the queries slow. I would like to use indexes, but even though I set them, they are not being used.

[Here is my table.](http://s28.postimg.org/nxhw94hu5/sql2.png) and [here is the result of using EXPLAIN.](http://s28.postimg.org/ylln7yrt9/sql1.png)

This is my query:

```
SELECT '' checkbox,
       k00_eszkozid,
       k00_eszkoznev,
       k01_gyariszam,
       k01_leltszam,
       prsn_name,
       k00_status,
       tstikon,
       k00_startflow,
       tstname,
       k00_eszkozid,
       k01_gyariszam,
       k01_leltszam
FROM   karton00
       LEFT JOIN karton01
              ON k00_eszkozid = k01_eszkozid
                 AND k01_status = 'A'
       LEFT JOIN karton02
              ON k00_eszkozid = k02_eszkozid
                 AND k02_status = 'A'
       LEFT JOIN karton04
              ON k00_eszkozid = k04_eszkozid
                 AND k04_status = 'A'
       LEFT JOIN karton05
              ON k00_eszkozid = k05_eszkozid
                 AND k05_status = 'A'
       LEFT JOIN karton06
              ON k00_eszkozid = k06_eszkozid
                 AND k06_status = 'A'
       LEFT JOIN karton08
              ON k00_eszkozid = k08_eszkozid
                 AND k08_status = 'A'
       LEFT JOIN karton09
              ON k00_eszkozid = k09_eszkozid
                 AND k09_status = 'A'
       LEFT JOIN telephely et
              ON k06_telephelyid = et.telepid
       LEFT JOIN ktghely00 ek
              ON k02_ktghid = ek.ktghid
       LEFT JOIN person00 us
              ON k06_userid = prsn_id
       LEFT JOIN ktghely00 fk
              ON prsn_ktgh = fk.ktghid
       LEFT JOIN telephely ft
              ON prsn_telep = ft.telepid
       LEFT JOIN tamstatus
              ON k02_tamstatusid = tstid
       LEFT JOIN szakleltar
              ON k02_szakleltarid = szleltid
       LEFT JOIN tamszerv
              ON k02_tamszervid = tszid
       LEFT JOIN ktghely01
              ON k02_vgazdaid = vgid
                 AND vgstatus = 'A'
       LEFT JOIN ktghely00 vk
              ON vgktghid = vk.ktghid
       LEFT JOIN szallitok m
              ON k05_mincegid = m.szallid
       LEFT JOIN szallitok s
              ON k04_szallitoid = s.szallid
       LEFT JOIN dctnry00 ym
              ON k05_minosit = ym.dctnryname
                 AND ym.dctnrygrp = 'YESNO'
       LEFT JOIN dctnry00 yd
              ON k05_check = yd.dctnryname
                 AND yd.dctnrygrp = 'YESNO'
WHERE  k00_status IN ( 'A', 'H' )
       AND ( k02_vgazdaid IN ( 7 ) )
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                       FROM   eszkozkizar
                       WHERE  ez_flid = 0
                              AND ez_emintaid = k00_eszkozmintaid
                              AND k00_uzembedatum < ( Date_add(Curdate(),
                                                      INTERVAL ez_honap month) )
                              AND k00_uzembedatum != ''
                              AND k02_vgazdaid NOT IN ( 7 ))
       AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
                      FROM   eszkozkizar
                      WHERE  ez_flid = 0
                             AND ez_emintaid = k00_eszkozmintaid
                             AND k02_tamszervid = ez_tamszerv
                             AND k02_tamstatusid = ez_tamsts
                             AND k00_uzembedatum < ( Date_add(Curdate(),
                                                     INTERVAL ez_honap month) )
                             AND k00_uzembedatum != ''
                             AND k02_vgazdaid NOT IN ( 7 ))
ORDER  BY k00_eszkoznev ASC;
```

Comment: What about cleaning and formatting a bit your question ?

Comment: Can you help us understand why you're joining the table to itself so many times? Perhaps give us a sample data set with the results you're trying to get and we can suggest a better way to approach your problem.

Comment: Additionally, aside from all the joins, you should qualify your columns as table.column so we know what is really involved in the query, and if extra tables are never really applicable (via left-joins), why include them.

Comment: You appear to be missing `karton03`.  Any time there's a `<tablename><number>` pattern, I'm worried about design problems.

Answer (score -1):

Also you can use `USE INDEX (index_list)` statement: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-hints.html

Comment: Unless you know _for a fact_ that specifying a specific index will help, it's best to let the optimizer do the work for you.  Any statements with these **need** to be reviewed on a regular basis, to ensure db changes don't make something else a better choice (that's why there are optimizers).  This type of thing is the equivalent of always driving down a specific road (or choosing it first)... regardless of traffic, new roads, detours, or potentially even your destination moving.